# Cache File Could not be written Typo3 6.0.4

Tags: apache, typo3

I work with Typo3 6.0.4. I've usually the same error:

Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1204026251: The temporary cache file "/typo3temp/Cache/Data/t3lib_l10n/519dc2b3ea684.temp" could not be written.

I found that the cache files in the typo3temp directory doesn't have the 777 permissions.

I tried to give the permission. But the problem is, if the typo3 writes a new cache file this file will have the permission 644.

Could anybody help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably ran into a race condition which is described in http://forge.typo3.org/issues/46205 and has been fixed in 6.0.5

Try to update to TYPO3 6.0.6 (or the latest patch level release 6.0.x) and then to clear your /typo3temp/Cache/ folder